# Header Sent for Static Extensionless Files

Tags: php, caching

I am plannig to set up something similar to the following:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6109/how-can-i-lock-down-an-old-wordpress-install-i-dont-intend-to-update

Basically the folders and files are generated like a cache for a php site.

What header info is sent for extensionless files?  Is the header info stored in the text file like the modified date or something else?
I would like to stop using extensions for all site content.
For example:

```
/about - html page
/js - my sites javascript with appropriate header info
/logo - my sites logo
etc.
```

Are there any  negatives or repercussions in setting extensionless files.
What about if I set up the caching system?

Comment: var_dump your $_SERVER variable and you will get your information

Comment: @Ibrahim Diallo = I am pretty sure that does not catch what the server sends to the client...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to set headers for static files, if they have no extension. For a whole directory it's easiest to use [`DefaulType`](http://www.google.com/search?q=DefaulType) in the `.htaccess`:

```
 # js/ directory
 DefaultType application/javascript
```

The sibling [`ForceType`](http://www.google.com/search?q=ForceType) is sometimes also useful:

```
 <Files about>
     ForceType text/html
 </Files>
```

But you can also set headers for individual files using e.g. a [`RewriteRule`](http://www.google.com/search?q=RewriteRule):

```
 RewriteRule logo - [T=image/jpeg]
```

And another option is to use [`mod_meta`](http://www.google.com/search?q=mod_meta). This allows to have each static file accompanied by a .meta file, which defines the sent MIME type.

Comment: mode_meta seems perfect, how would I create the meta file form a php script?  I can save the content using `ob_start()` but I'm unsure how to generate the meta file.

Comment: Just create an extra file containing just the MIME header: `file_put_contents("$fn.meta", "Content-Type: text/html");` - The module is actually called mod_cern_meta for Apache http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_cern_meta.html - and take care to configure the `MetaDir .` and `MetaSuffix .meta` for it to work that easily.

Answer (score 0):

1. Headers are being attached by the web server
2. Send a static file and you can see with Firebug or a similar tool what headers are being sent
3. To override a header that was attached by the server, you can use PHP's `header` function. Use the same header name as the one you want to override. For example, if you want to override\cancel the `Content-Length` header you would do `header('Content-Length: ')` (Although for this specific header it makes no sense to cancel it).
4. To attach headers to static files, you will need to do that (in Apache) in .htacces or the main configuration file of the Apache.

Comment: In php you send headers like so `header('...')`.  Don't those headers therefore override whatever the web server my send by default?

Comment: @Lime - yes, that is exactly the way to override server issued headers.

Comment: So would these php override headers be coupled with the file if I generate a static cached version?  Do the headers bundle with the file like modify date and time?

Comment: @lime - by static files I assume you mean HTML. You have no way to attach headers to HTML files - inside the files. You will need to tweak the server itself for that.